# Scrollbar laggy with images in sliverlist when we scroll

Tags: flutter, performance, scrollbar, flutter-sliver

I use a SliverList to show a list of posts with images.
But when i scroll down in this list, i feel so laggy with scrollbar.

Anyone has a solution ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you loading very high resolution images when you scroll? This could a cause for your issue. Try loading lower resolution imaegs first.

Comment: Hello @ZonilyJame, i optimised images with a small resolution. I found a problem that a sliverlist renders only posts which are visible on the screen. Do we can make a custom for sliverlist to render all items or have a cacheExtent as ListView ?